# To transpose and style dataframe in python pandas

Tags: python, dataframe, transpose

I have a data frame of the following order

```
Date      Material    Qty
5/15/21      J1       50
5/16/21      K2       40
6/02/21      K3       30
7/03/21      R1       90
```

which transform into this

```
Material  5/15/21   5/16/21  6/02/21 7/03/21
J1         50       
K2                    40
K3                             30
R1                                      90
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `pivot`

```
df.pivot('Material', 'Date', 'Qty')

Date      5/15/21  5/16/21  6/02/21  7/03/21
Material                                    
J1           50.0      NaN      NaN      NaN
K2            NaN     40.0      NaN      NaN
K3            NaN      NaN     30.0      NaN
R1            NaN      NaN      NaN     90.0
```

or `unstack`

```
df.set_index(['Date', 'Material']).unstack(level=0)
```

If you want to sum duplicate values

```
d = {'Date': {0: '5/15/21',
  1: '5/16/21',
  2: '6/02/21',
  3: '7/03/21',
  4: '5/15/21'},
 'Material': {0: 'J1', 1: 'K2', 2: 'K3', 3: 'R1', 4: 'J1'},
 'Qty': {0: 50.0, 1: 40.0, 2: 30.0, 3: 90.0, 4: 20}}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)

df.groupby(['Date', 'Material'])['Qty'].sum().unstack(level=0)
```

Comment: Thanks alot!!! If i J1 is duplicating with different Qty and i want to add and save in a single value.

Comment: @RahnaK.M a different quantity for the same date? If so, `df.groupby(['Date', 'Material'])['Qty'].sum().unstack(level=0)`

Comment: sum() worked for me. But after group by months get sorted like this: Aug21 July 21 and June21. How this can be rectified?

Comment: @RahnaK.M you need to convert your date column to datetime format first.

Comment: I resolved issue by turing off sort in group By.d=data.groupby([' Month', 'Material'],sort=False)['Qty'].sum().unstack(level=0)